# How to put input of a function in the name of text file?

Tags: r

```
 myf<- function(col,row){
 x=5*col+row
 write.table(x,"res_row_col.txt")}
 myf(5,6)
```

I expected the file to be:

```
         res_5_6.txt
```

But the file was written as:

```
      res_row_col.txt
```

Comment: On a side note take a minute to imagine how terrible it would be if what you expected to happen was the norm.  How would you ever be able to print a string of literal text that you want to print?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the paste0 function:

```
myf<- function(col,row){
x=5*col+row
write.table(x,paste0("res_", row, "_", col, ".txt"))}
myf(5,6)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using row and col as string in "res_row_col", 
you have to 'expend' them to write what is inside the variables.

Maybe something like that by cutting the string and using concatenation : 
"res_" . row . "_" . col